# Error with Vite and AWS SDK: net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vite

I'm working on a project that uses Vite and React, and I am trying to integrate AWS S3 to upload images. I've imported the AWS SDK using the @aws-sdk/client-s3 package. However, I'm encountering an issue where my local server fails with the following error message in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@aws-sdk_client-s3.js?v=08d883e2 net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep)
```

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
import AWS from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { dataUrlToBlob } from './dataUrlToBlob';

const s3 = new AWS.S3Client({
    credentials: 
        {
            accessKeyId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AWS_REGION
        }
});

export async function uploadImageToS3(dataUrl, filename) {
    const blob = dataUrlToBlob(dataUrl);
    const uniqueFilename = `${uuidv4()}-${filename}`;

    const params = {
        Bucket: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: uniqueFilename,
        Body: blob,
        ContentType: blob.type,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    const command = new AWS.PutObjectCommand(params)

    try {
        // const data = await s3.send(command);
        console.log(`Image uploaded successfully at ${data} location - ${data.Location} key - ${data.key}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Failed to upload image to S3: ${error}`);
    }
}
```